# Issue when using sqldf() to manipulate a data frame

Tags: r, sqldf

```
data_processed <- sqldf(" select a.permno, a.number, a.mean, b.ret as med, a.std
                  from data_processed as a
                  left join data_processed2 as b
                  on a.permno=b.permno")
```

The code above is not working. I an getting the error below:

> Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : no such column: b.ret

Here is my data:

1. data_processed:

```
   permno number         mean        std
1   10107    120 0.0117174000 0.06802718
2   11850    120 0.0024398083 0.04594591
3   12060    120 0.0005072167 0.08544500
4   12490    120 0.0063569167 0.05325215
5   14593    120 0.0200060583 0.08865493
6   19561    120 0.0154743500 0.07771348
7   25785    120 0.0184815583 0.16510082
8   27983    120 0.0025951333 0.09538822
9   55976    120 0.0092889000 0.04812975
10  59328    120 0.0098526167 0.07135423
```

2. data_processed2:

```
     permno     return
1   10107  0.0191920
2   11850  0.0015495
3   12060 -0.0040130
4   12490  0.0078245
5   14593  0.0231735
6   19561  0.0202610
7   25785 -0.0018760
8   27983  0.0027375
9   55976  0.0089435
10  59328  0.0166490
```

Comment: is it that `data_processed2` doesn't have column names?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention about

Comment: permno     return
1   10107  0.0191920
2   11850  0.0015495
3   12060 -0.0040130
4   12490  0.0078245
5   14593  0.0231735
6   19561  0.0202610
7   25785 -0.0018760
8   27983  0.0027375
9   55976  0.0089435
10  59328  0.0166490

Comment: permno         return                  are the column names

Comment: If return is the column name you should use b.return in the select statement